# Configure Spring to use a default Configuration class when running tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When running unit test I typically start with something like this

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [TestConfig::class])
class ParcelCodeControllerTest {
```

Is there some way I could avoid having to add the `@ContextConfiguration(classes = [TestConfig::class])` annotation to every file, instead configuring Spring to by default use `TestConfig` as the configuration class?

I could not see anything like this when browsing relative new [Spring Boot 3.1. features](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the simplest solution would be to create a custom composed annotation as most of the test-related annotations can be used as [meta-annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/classpath-scanning.html#beans-meta-annotations) according to [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/annotations/integration-meta.html).

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomSpringBootTest {
  @AliasFor(annotation = ContextConfiguration.class, attribute = "classes")
  Class<?>[] classes() default {TestConfig.class};
}
```

Comment: certainly a good tip worth considering!